# C++ win32 API Create multiple windows like viewports

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to build a Level Editor for my engine and I wondered how I can achieve multiple viewport windows in one window, like in Blender, Cinema 4D or Unity, where you have your rendering viewport, scene hierarchy, properties window etc.

Does the win32 API have a function to create these viewport windows or do I have to create another instance with `CreateWindowW` with no title bar?

Comment: I believe you need to use CreateWindow

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably do this with a single window but this sort of thing is usually much easier achieved using a child window ((yes, created via CreateWindow(Ex)?) for each view and then a parent window that handles positioning those child windows (that is, a spliter type frame).

You may even end up with a window tree that is separate from the level view for a properties list etc.

It is simply much easier for the child windows to only need handle one thing (show an overhead level view, show a 3D projection etc) than to make one window class that does all of these.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native notion of a "viewport" in Win32.

To support this kind of functionality at all, to create even a single viewport, you will need to know how to create a custom control. In Win32 "custom controls" are really just custom child windows. Say you have a custom child window class called "view" that handles rendering using a 3D library in its WM_PAINT handler, etc., then to support multiple viewports you fundamentally have two options:

1. Make "view" implement the functionality itself. Multiple viewports would not be separate Win32 windows. There would be one Win32 child control painted to look as though it was multiple windows. You would then need to handle all the internal UI interactions you offer the user 100% yourself. Dragging the view splitter bar, etc. The benefit would be that you could then make those interactions however you want, possibly totally nonstandard, and also performance while dragging and performing other interactions would probably be better than the alternative.
2. Use separate "view" child windows for each viewport. Handle UI interactions via other custom child controls, possibly, e.g. a view splitter control, etc.

Without more focus to the question that is about as much of an answer as can be given. The key thing to understand is that Win32 is a powerful but low-level API. If you are looking for an application framework that gives you a lot of functionality for free you should look somewhere else.

Comment: There is a very *distinct* notion of a viewport in the Windows API. [Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/coordinate-spaces-and-transformations) gets you started, if that is news to you. It's possibly not the same *"viewport"* the OP is talking about, yet claiming that there were no native notion to the term is just wrong.